# Event handling API in the browser besides for DOM?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events

I was curious to know what sort of event-handling APIs browsers have, and how I could use these in some JavaScript logic that doesn't deal with DOM at all, so I gave `Event` a try.

Apparently, `Event` and `CustomEvent` are meant to be used only with DOM, and I don't see any other API, so I ended up creating a "dummy" `<div>` element as an event handler (EventTarget) in order to communicate between two parts of code, something like:

```
// shared file
export
let eventHandler = document.createElement('div')

// ... some other file
import {eventHandler} from './sharedFile'
eventHandler.addEventListener('foobar', function(event) {
  console.log('foobar event fired!')
})

// ... some other file
import {eventHandler} from './sharedFile'
console.log('About to trigger "foobar" event.')
eventHandler.dispatchEvent(new Event('foobar'))
```

This works, but as you can see, I've created a `<div>` element that I'm not going to use in the DOM at all, and only use it as an event handling mechanism.

It seems like a waste to create a DOM element that I'm not going to use as a DOM element. Is there any other way to do it with native browser APIs, or do we have to create our own (or use an) event library to avoid creating a dummy element?

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript objects and functions to create your own event bus without using the DOM.

The basic idea is that you can define an API for registering callbacks and dispatching events, like this:

```
var EventBus = (function() {
    var listeners = {};
    return {
        'addEventListener': function(eventName, callback) {
            if (!listeners[eventName]) {
                listeners[eventName] = [];
            }
            listeners[eventName].push(callback);
        },
        'dispatchEvent': function(event) {
            if (listeneres[eventName]) {
                listeners[event.name].forEach(function(callback) {
                    callback(event);
                });
            }
        }
    }
}());
```

Comment: That's what I thought, that we need to implement it ourselves. As you've shown, it's easy to do. I'm curious to know why W3C would couple the browser API to the DOM instead of making it more useful and generic for non-DOM use cases.